Is there any method to make sure a electroplated layer of iron oxidizes into magnetite (Fe3O4) instead of hematite (Fe2O3)?

I am currently electroplating iron on copper using a DIY setup in my lab. Steel sheet as anode with electrolyte having 5% acetic acid with sodium carbonate to form sodium acetate and added some NaCl to increase conductivity. I am trying to get a magnetite plating. Is there any way I can control the oxidation to form magnetite instead of hematite? I read somewhere that Iron in salt water oxidizes into magnetite and I tried something similar and it seems a darker layer has formed I am not sure if this is hematite can anyone tell me what process is occurring and is this really hematite? Is there any other way to get  this done efficiently?
